# ¿Cómo localizar una sublista sin conocer todos sus elementos?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer una lista de listas en Python de la forma (por ejemplo):

```
lista = [[1,4,1],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

def funcion(argumento1, argumento2):
    
    if [argumento1, argumento2] in lista:
        lugar = lista.index([argumento1, argumento2])
        lista [lugar][1] += 12
        print (lista)

funcion(1,4)
```

La idea es que simplemente al proporcionarle los dos primeros argumentos de la lista sea capaz de reconocer la línea y cambiar el tercer argumento, pero no consigo que reconozca los dos argumentos sin proporcionar el tercero, ya que de la forma en la he escrito el código no ejecuta lo que hay dentro del if.

Comment: `for sublista in lista: if  [argumento1, argumento2] == sublista[:2]: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lista = [[1,4,1],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

def modificarLista(elemento1, elemento2):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i][0] == elemento1 and lista[i][1] == elemento2:
            lista[i][2] += 12

modificarLista(1,4)
print(lista)
```

Dado que tienes listas dentro de una lista, para acceder a un elemento tienes que indicar primero la lista (0, 1 o 2) y despúes la posición del elemento en la lista. Por ejemplo, para acceder al segundo elemento de la primera lista: `lista[0][1]`.

En la lista correspondiente se suma 12 al tercer elemento, como tú querías.

El resultado es:

```
[[1, 4, 13], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

He aquí una solución genérica, sin limitaciones en cuanto al tamaño de las secuencias:

```
def funcion(lista, *argumentos):
    for sublista in lista:
        for i in range(len(argumentos)):
            if sublista[i] != argumentos[i]:
                break
        else:
            return sublista
    return None
```

La función recibe una lista con las secuencias válidas, y luego una cantidad variable de valores que forman la subsecuencia a buscar.

La notación `*argumentos` en la declaración de la función indica que se recojan todos los restantes argumentos en la invocación y se pongan en una tupla llamada `argumentos`, la que puedo recorrer dentro de la función.

La función procede a examinar cada secuencia válida (extraída de `lista`). Por cada una, recorre en conjunto la secuencia y los argumentos (otra lista). Si todos son iguales, retorna la secuencia completa.

Si no se encuentra la secuencia, retorna `None`

**Demo**

```
lista1 = [[1, 4, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
print(funcion(lista1, 1, 4))
print(funcion(lista1, 5, 6))

lista2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
print(funcion(lista2, 1))
print(funcion(lista2, 10, 11, 12))
print(funcion(lista2, 7, 8))
```

produce:

```
[1, 4, 1]
[5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
None
```